# Eliminate all leading zeroes of an expression

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to eliminate the leading zeros of this kind of string:

```
"045 + 0000010*10"
```

to get:

```
"45 + 10*10"
```

Comment: Is your desirted output "45 + 0000010*10" or "45 + 10*10" ?

Comment: @Fildo: I am trying to get "45 +10*10".

Comment: Why do you need to do that? Are you aware that `int("00010") == 10`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple [regex replacement](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) can get the job done nicely:

```py
>>> import re
>>> expr = "045 + 0000010*10"
>>> re.sub(r"\b0+", '', expr)
'45 + 10*10'
```

- `\b` - word boundary (non-consuming)
- `0+` - literal zero, repeated 1 or more times

As the `\b` is non-consuming, this will only replace the `0`s with an empty string.

[RegEx demo](https://regex101.com/r/2PfL7W/1) ; [Code demo](https://repl.it/@TomerKalish/PoshPeruBetatest#main.py)

Answer (score 0):

You can build on this:

```
s = "045 + 000010*15"
s = " ".join(x.lstrip("0") for x in s.split())
```

Which does:

```
end = []
for x in s.split():
    end.append(x.lstrip("0"))
s = " ".join(end)
```

I.e. strips "0" from left side of each word in a string.
If you need to be able to strip from numbers not separated by whitespaces as well, use .replace() or .translate(), before splitting the string, to replace operators for example:

```
s = s.replace("*", " * ")
```